# Using formulas for text objects

Tags: sql, formulas

I'm using Crystal XI R2 with Oracle 10g and I want to create labels (text objects) based on some table fields.
All labels should be result of a formula (ID=1, ID=2... and so on) and what I want is to create a formula that retrieves the field value where ID=1 but what I'm getting is a bolean like "true" or "False".

I've been searching but I can't find a way to do this and I'm pretty sure this is a simple thing to do.

In SQL is something like:
    SELECT {field}
    FROM {table}
    WHERE ID=1;

but I can't make it work. Anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance